# How to Disable Keyboard Key with CSS?

Tags: css

Can we disable keyboard key (Ctrl+A/Ctrl+C) with CSS, so that nobody can use select all shortcut using keyboard in my website?

Comment: What sense does that make? If I can't use the shortcuts, I select with the mouse and choose copy from the right click menu

Comment: It might to better to explain what you are trying to stop people from copying. Most likely you can make it awkward but you can't make it impossible.

Comment: Honestly, if you don't want something to be copied; you may not want to put it on the internet. @popnoodles is right, there is no way to make it impossible.

Comment: There is a hot topic about it on [webmasters stackexchange site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39392/how-to-disallow-selection-of-text-on-website/39396#39396). it could be useful.

Comment: Why do you think CSS is the tool for the job?

Comment: I used java script also. But all I want disable keyboard shortcut when java script is disabled on browser.

Comment: CSS isn't some kind of JavaScript fallback, you know...

Answer (score 13):

No, CSS cannot affect the browser's response to the keyboard. JavaScript can, but JavaScript can also be turned off.

In other words: you can't do that, and even if you do then you can't count on it.

Comment: I have disabled text selection by mouse with css, But cant do anything with keyboard short cut

Comment: As CSS affect browser's response to mouse, so I thought it may also work for keyboard as well

Answer (score 6):

Might not exactly be the functionality you're looking for, but if it's a small number of elements where you want to exclude a user from focusing, you can go into the html and add `tabindex="-1"` on that element, which removes it from the keyboard focus list

```
<div tabindex="-1">element text</div>
```

and also use this css

```
 .disable{
            pointer-events:none;
            background:#e9ecef;
         }
```

Comment: This is what I needed for a different problem, thank you! I was trying to prevent focus of elements while a form was in the process of submitting.

Answer (score 4):

Try this css

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

(from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting))

Though the original question was about selecting text with the mouse, this css seems to disable the ctrl+a / ctrl+c capability as well (at least in a quick test on a sample project)

Comment: I was also thinking about this. I wish this code could be modified for disabling keyboard keys as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not with CSS, however it's possible using JavaScript if the browser doesn't have the feature disabled.